# Animations for overlaping fragment right to left and left to right according material design

Tags: android, animation, fragment, material-design, overlap

I'm trying to implement solution for overlapping one fragment by another like recommended in Google material design docs but unfortunately I haven't find a way to do it for api v9 (android 2.3)
Can somebody help me with it? I would appreciate xml example of animation but code also be ok.

[Link with animation](https://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/v_2/material_ext_publish/0B0NGgBg38lWWcUtiOTBCN2o0WWc/animation-meaningfultransitions-visualcontinuity-030301_PhotoList_Do_xhdpi_002.webm)

[Animation Meaningful transitions page in Google docs](https://www.google.com/design/spec/animation/meaningful-transitions.html#meaningful-transitions-visual-continuity)

Comment: Did you found the solution? If yes then kindly post it.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it on actual api v9 device but all stuff is available since lower APIs, so please try it:

When going from `activity1` to `activity2` use:

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.shade);
```

when going back use:

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.unshade, R.anim.slide_out_right);
```

Where:

`slide_in_right.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator" >
    <translate android:duration="1000" android:fromXDelta="100%" android:toXDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

`shade.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator">
    <alpha android:duration="1000" android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.7" />
</set>
```

`unshade.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator">
    <alpha android:duration="1000" android:fromAlpha="0.7" android:toAlpha="1" />
</set>
```

`slide_out_right.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator" >
    <translate android:duration="1000" android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="100%"/>
</set>
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement a BaseActivity in your code which extends Activity and inside its `onCreate()` implement this

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //opening transition animations
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.activity_open_translate,R.anim.activity_close_scale);
    }
```

Create the two anim files.The snippet for `activity_open_translate` is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <translate android:fromXDelta="100%"
               android:toXDelta="0%"
               android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />

</set>
```

and the snippet for `activty_close_scale` is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <scale android:fromXScale="100%p"
           android:toXScale="80%p"
           android:fromYScale="100%p"
           android:toYScale="80%p"
           android:pivotX="50%p"
           android:pivotY="50%p"
           android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />

    <alpha android:fromAlpha="1"
           android:toAlpha="0.5"
           android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>

</set>
```

Now all you have to do is extend this BaseActivity class to the Activity you want